# name 'A' is not defined

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to learn opencv using python, when I try to define a variable, I got the same error.

this is my code

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 

img = cv2. imread('love.jpg', 1)
cv2. imshow('image', img)

A == cv2.waitkey(0) & 0xFF

if A == 27:
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

elif A ==   ord('s'):
cv2.imwrite('love.png', img)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and this is the result

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

I thing the problem in installing python in my device ( windows 10, 64 bit)

Comment: Remove one of the `=` signs in `A == cv2.waitkey(0) & 0xFF`

Comment: You want a single '=' sign here: `A == cv2.waitkey(0) & 0xFF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the truth value of A with `A == cv2.waitkey(0) & 0xFF` before you set the variable A. Instead use `A = somecode` to initialize the variable. == is a boolean operator (see docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)).